# Convert .po file into ICU4C .txt file

Tags: sed, localization, gettext, data-conversion, icu

I've tried to create an [ICU4C file](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/localizing#TOC-ICU4C) from a gettext .po file with a `sed` script like this:

```
/^#/ d                            /* delete comments */
:a;/"$/{N;s/"\n"//;ba}            /* merge quoted lines in loop */
/^msgid /s/msgid (.*)/\1/         /* convert msgids */
s/msgstr "(.*)"/\{ "\1" }/        /* convert msgstrs */
```

and it already works pretty well (ignoring plural forms), but for some reason it doesn't convert the last msgid/msgstr couple, unless I don't merge the quotes twice. But then the syntax for the other stuff becomes wrong. Any ideas? Doesn't have to use `sed`.

Those ICU files are the only ones accepted by `genrb`, and I'd like to use the ResourceBundle in PHP.

Comment: I believe that after the `N`, you've likely got `quoteline"\nmsgid` in the pattern space, and `^` is only going to match if `msgid` is at the beginning of the pattern space.  It matches `\0msgid` not `\nmsgid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accomplished my goal through a shell script. Here's the rough idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# remove comments
sed -r -e '/^#/ d' < de.po >de.icu.txt
# merge strings
sed -i de.icu.txt -r -e ':L;/"$/{N;s/"\n"//;b L}'
# delete gettext header
sed -i -e '1,2 d' de.icu.txt
# convert into ICU format
sed -i de.icu.txt -r -e '
# delete untranslated
/msgid ".+"/{
    N
    /msgstr ""/{
        N;s/msgid ".+"\nmsgstr ""\n//
    }
}
# generate ICU txt
/msgid /s/msgid (.*)/\1/
s/msgstr "(.*)"/\{ "\1" }/'
sed -i -e '1i de {' -e '$ a\\n}' de.icu.txt
```

There's probably a nicer way, but it does the job.